# How to display .RGB on uiimageview

Tags: ios4, uiimageview, uiimagepngrepresentation

I am having file with extension .RGB and need to display it on uiimageview.

For this i need to convert the .RGB format to specific format like .PNG or .JPEG however unable to get it right .
I tried with following code for this.

```
    UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Attachment.RGB"];
CGImageRef imageRef=[image CGImage];
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);
UIImage* imageFinal = [UIImage imageWithData:pngData];

image_view.image=imageFinal;
```

There are online websites which can convert the RGB to visible image .But i didn't found any solution for objective c .
Can any one help me on this .

Regards 
Pagyyy123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the readtex.c for this which is open source implementations for this.. see the sample following code snippets...

```
static TK_RGBImageRec *tkRGBImageLoad(const char *fileName)
{
   rawImageRec *raw;
   TK_RGBImageRec *final;

   raw = RawImageOpen(fileName);
   if (!raw) {
      fprintf(stderr, "File not found\n");
      return NULL;
   }
   final = (TK_RGBImageRec *)malloc(sizeof(TK_RGBImageRec));
   if (final == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory!\n");
      return NULL;
   }
   final->sizeX = raw->sizeX;
   final->sizeY = raw->sizeY;
   final->components = raw->sizeZ;
   RawImageGetData(raw, final);
   RawImageClose(raw);
   return final;
}
```

http://opensource.apple.com/source/X11server/X11server-85/mesa/Mesa-7.2/progs/util/readtex.c

I hope the above URL will help.

Comment: Thnx for ur help let me ty this

Comment: i used the source files from the above link but it is giving following error 'GL/gl.h' file not found .Do i need to add any framework for this .

Comment: thnx it help lot after lot of efforts i successfully displayed the image on uiimage view .....